Breaker issue 20A
My power goes off when the A/C mini split comes on. About 2 hours later it will come back on. Without touching the 20A breaker. Could this be a bad breaker?

Is the power completely off, or stuff does not work?  I would turn off the breaker and check all wire connections for tightness(a torque driver should be used).  2 hours might also be a temperature/heat protection for the motor.  If mini-split and connections check out, then maybe the breaker.

Loose connection somewhere.
